# Unable to hide iOS toolbar when function is called

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm building a meme generator and I'm attempting to hide the toolbar when an action is completed. I'm unsure as to why the toolbar is always visible.

```
func generateMemedImage() -> UIImage {
        navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: false)

        // Render view to an image
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size)
        view.drawHierarchy(in: self.view.frame, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        let memedImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(true, animated: false)
        return memedImage
    }
```

That function is called by the following function:

```
func save() {
        let memedImage = generateMemedImage()
        let meme = Meme(topText: topTextField.text!, bottomText: bottomTextField.text!, originalImage: imagePickerView.image!, memedImage: memedImage)
        // Add it to the memes array in the Application Delegate
        let object = UIApplication.shared.delegate
        let appDelegate = object as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.memes.append(meme)
        print(appDelegate.memes.count)
    }
```

Which is then called by the following IBAction:

```
@IBAction func shareMeme(_ sender: Any) {
        let memedImage = generateMemedImage()
        let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [memedImage], applicationActivities: nil)

        activityVC.completionWithItemsHandler = {
            activity, completed, items, error in
            if completed {
                self.save()
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
        present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

I have tried flipping the Bool states in the follow with no luck. Where am I going wrong? [Here](https://github.com/andrewTuzson/memeGenerator) is a link to the repo as well.

Comment: Can you also show where you call `generateMemedImage()`?

Comment: Sorry about that. See my update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assuming to interact with the default toolbar nested in the `NavigationController` (`navigationController?.setToolbarHidden`), but the fact is that you defined a custom `UIToolBar` inside your `Storyboard/ViewController`:

[image]

So to be able to switch the visibility of your custom `UIToolBar` you should first, attach the outlet doing so:

```
@IBOutlet weak var toolbar: UIToolbar!
```

and then whenever you want to hide it:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: { self.toolbar.alpha = 0 })
```

or show it:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: { self.toolbar.alpha = 1 })
```

Comment: This will hide the toolbar visually but I believe the toolbar will still be interactable afterwards.

Comment: I don't know what Andrew is going to do with such `UIToolBar`, if he wish to disable it then `self.toolbar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true/false` should be enough.

Comment: Yup, that 100% did the trick. This is all pretty new to me, so I am missing little things like this. Very helpful; thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `activityVC.completionWithItemsHandler` is called asynchronously from a thread other than the main one. Any UI update should always be called from the main thread and doing otherwise usually results in weird behavior.

In your case, you can try calling `save()` from the main thread as that is the method calling `generateMemedImage()`. It should look something like this:

```
...

if completed {
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.save()
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}

...
```

Note that if saving takes too long, your UI may get clunky as the main thread will be blocked while saving. If that is the case, you may need to try a different logic for saving.

One other thing you need to be careful about is how you show/hide the toolbar. You are calling `navigationController?.setToolbarHidden()` twice in the same method, to show and then hide it. However, what you need to take into account is that UI updates are not executed instantly, but rather they are queued in the main thread to be executed after your method returns. So, leaving them as they are right now will not show/hide the toolbar.

This is not really an answer but these are things you need to take into consideration in your implementation.